# Getting data from a different collection while performing aggregation on a different collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have a collection named `Vote` that looks like the following:

```
{
  postId: "1",
  comment:{ 
    text_sentiment: "positive",
    topic: "A"
  }
}, // DOC-1

{
  postId: "2",
  comment:{ 
     text_sentiment: "negative",
     topic: "A"
  }
}, // DOC-2

{
  postId: "3",
  comment:{ 
     text_sentiment: "positive",
     topic: "B"
  }
},..//DOC-3 ..
```

and a collection named `post` which looks as follows?

```
{
  _id: "1",
  category: "a"
},
{
  _id: "2",
  category: "b",
}
```

I want to do an aggregation on this collection such that it returns the following structure. (which also takes into account the other `post` collection`

```
[
   {
      _id: "hash",
      topic: "A",
      topicOccurance: 2,
      sentiment: {
        positive: 1,
        negative: 1,
        neutral: 0
      },
      postIds: [1,2],
      categories: [a,b]
   },
   ..
]
```

I created the following aggregation:

```
    db.Vote.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            surveyId: "e6d38e1ecd",
            "comment.topic": {
                $exists: 1
            },

        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                topic: "$comment.topic",
                text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
            },
            total: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            postIds: {
                $push: "$postId"
            }

        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.topic",
            total: {
                $sum: "$total"
            },
            text_sentiments: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
                    v: "$total"
                }
            },
            postIds: {
                "$push": "$postIds"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            topic: "$_id",
            topicOccurance: "$total",
            sentiment: {
                "$arrayToObject": "$text_sentiments"
            },
            postIds: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$postIds",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                      "$$value",
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "topicOccurance": -1
        }
    }
])
```

This works fine but I do not know, how to also get `categories` which exist in a separate collection named `posts`. How can I query a different collection while performing aggregation?

Comment: Are you asking about [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `$lookup` will suffice:

```
db.Vote.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "comment.topic": {
        $exists: 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        topic: "$comment.topic",
        text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      postIds: {
        $push: "$postId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.topic",
      total: {
        $sum: "$total"
      },
      text_sentiments: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
          v: "$total"
        }
      },
      postIds: {
        "$push": "$postIds"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      topic: "$_id",
      topicOccurance: "$total",
      sentiment: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$text_sentiments"
      },
      postIds: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$postIds",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "topicOccurance": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "post",
      localField: "postIds",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "categories"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      categories: {
        "$setUnion": {
          $map: {
            input: "$categories",
            in: "$$this.category"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IDE7yRRoTvi)

Comment: Could you explain `as: categories` and what is happening inside `addFields`?

Comment: Sure, the lookup returns an array of documents, and you wanted an array of string values. so that `$addFields` is just converting an array of documents into an array of strings.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce duplicate values from `postIds`?

Comment: yea, you can use `$setUnion` the exact way i'm using it to remove duplicate categories https://mongoplayground.net/p/OuFwjgFHII_

Comment: Do you think this looks good https://mongoplayground.net/p/xb2nJndV162 ?

Comment: Could you help answer a related query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838497/getting-count-of-total-documents-when-using-aggregation-along-with-skip-and-limi