# Getting count of total documents when using aggregation along with skip and limit

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

How can I get the total count of documents when using the aggregation along with `limit` and `skip` like in the following query?

```
  db.Vote.aggregate({
       $match: {
           tid: "e6d38e1ecd",
           "comment.topic": {$exists: 1},
       }
   },{
       $group: {
           _id: {
               topic: "$comment.topic",
               text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
               
           },
           total: {$sum: 1},
           
       }
   },{
       $project: {
           topic: {
               name: "$_id.topic",
               occurence: "$total"
           },
           sentiment: "$_id.text_sentiment"
       }
   },{
       $sort: {"topic.occurence": -1}
   })
    .skip(SKIP)
    .limit(LIMIT)
```

Here I would always get the documents bounded by `LIMIT`, but at each query, I also want to know the total documents. How can I do that?

**EDIT**
While some of you have suggested using `$facet`, I am not sure how to use that. For example, the aggregation returns `50` documents without limit. How can I use `$facet` such that it not only returns `LIMIT` documents but also the meta-data that contains the total documents.

Here is a working query from [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OuFwjgFHII_) that I created. How can I use `$facet` or any other method to get the total count.

Comment: Or maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029987/using-count-within-an-addfield-operation-in-mongodb-aggregation/51030473#51030473

Comment: @Cristian-FlorinCalina Not able to understand. Do I need to copy the same aggregation code twice to get the count using `$facet`? Could you give an example?

Comment: No, you can add the `$facet` at the end, but the disadvantage is that it will group all your documents to one document, Hence I prefer the `$setWindowFeilds`

Comment: Do You want the document count after the group stage?

Comment: @nimrodserok Yes, after all the stages.

Comment: This was my answer to the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305624/how-to-use-mongodb-aggregation-for-pagination/48307554#48307554 evidently it was answered many times already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `$facet`, but the disadvantage is that it will group all your documents to one document:

```
db.Vote.aggregate(
  {$match: {tid: "e6d38e1ecd",  "comment.topic": {$exists: 1}}},
  {$group: {_id: {topic: "$comment.topic", text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"},
           total: {$sum: 1}}
   },
  {$project: {topic: {name: "$_id.topic",  occurence: "$total"},
           sentiment: "$_id.text_sentiment"}
  },
  {$facet: {
    data: [{$sort: {"topic.occurence": -1}}, {$skip: SKIP}, {$limit: LIMIT}],
    total: [{ $count: "total" }]
  }}
)
```

Other option is to use `$setWindowFields` to add the total count to each document, which allows to keep them as separate documents:

```
db.Vote.aggregate(
  {$match: {tid: "e6d38e1ecd",  "comment.topic": {$exists: 1}}},
  {$group: {_id: {topic: "$comment.topic", text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"},
           total: {$sum: 1}}
   },
  {$project: {topic: {name: "$_id.topic",  occurence: "$total"},
           sentiment: "$_id.text_sentiment"}
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {output: {totalCount: {$count: {}}}}
  })
    .skip(SKIP)
    .limit(LIMIT)
```

Comment: Could you please explain `setWindowFields`? What is happening here `{output: {totalCount: {$count: {}}}}`?

Comment: The `totalCount` field is being added to all documents with the same value: the total count. This allows you to NOT group all your documents into one big document, which is important since documents have size limitation

Comment: Does the statement `$count: {}` mean, get whatever is there in the output?

Comment: It means count the number of documents in this phase

Comment: Could you please explain what does `total: [{ $count: "total" }]` mean inside `facet`? What does `$count: "total"` mean? What is `total`?

Comment: "total" in this case is a string which will be the key name for the value of total. See [`$count`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)