# Get number of results from aggregate in mongo (using python)

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm using aggregate in order to get some documents ( I can't use find that way). I used to use the `.count()` function to know how many documents I got.
This function isn't working with aggregate. When I tried `$count` I just got the count without all the documents.
What else can I do?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838497/getting-count-of-total-documents-when-using-aggregation-along-with-skip-and-limi/72838622#72838622) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "$count" Within an "addField" Operation in MongoDB Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029987/using-count-within-an-addfield-operation-in-mongodb-aggregation)

Comment: Using ```$count``` return an object with the count, but not the documents it counted.

Comment: It is if used inside `$facet` or `$setWindowFields`

Comment: It's giving me the same result. I guess there's another way to use it

Answer (score 0):

try `.count_documents`
or ..
Does [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/#behavior) answer your question?
Just like this

```
pipeline = [
    {'$group': {'_id':None, 'count': {'$sum':1}}}
]
nums = m_collection.aggregate(pipeline)
print(list(nums))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding ```$group``` return an object with the count, but not the documents it counted. Any other function for counting is not working