# MongoDB exception Size must be between 0 and 16MB

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate, paging

I am using aggregate and facets to implement paging using skip and limit.One facet is used to get the paged data and another facet is used to get total order count.

```
Db.collection.Aggregate.Match(filter).Facet(facet1,facet2);
```

When passing page number as 4 and page size as 500, I am getting the exception from mongo db server as pipeline limit exceeds 16mb.I also tried aggregate option allowdiskuse as true,but no use.Can anyone help me regarding it.

Comment: One option is to use `$setWindowFields` to return the count instead of `$facet`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838497/getting-count-of-total-documents-when-using-aggregation-along-with-skip-and-limi) for example

Comment: But my real issue is not about getting the count.In the page number 4(page size 500) data,the total size of the documents exceeds 16 MB.How can I handle it

Answer (score 0):

I can guess, the `BSON` document size is more than what `mongodb` supports See:

[image: MongoDB Size for BSON]

> The maximum BSON document size is 16MB or 16777216 bytes.
> All conversions should use base-2 scale, e.g. 1024 kilobytes = 1
> megabyte.

REF: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: You need to make sure your data is compact and before fetching. If you are saving base64 strings you need to exclude those from result. Solution is subject to what you have on your end.